# Creating desktop entry or shortcut to launch an application in ubuntu-mate

Tags: shortcuts, ubuntu-mate

I want to launch Webstorm from the panel? I created a desktop entry in Webstorm application but i dont know how to access it ? Any input would be great. Thanks in advance.

OS: Ubuntu-mate 14.04 Lts.

Edit: I installed Webstorm by executing webstorm.sh file. In webstorm ide, go to tools-> Add desktop entry (this is how i created desktop entry).

Comment: could you please [edit] your question and explain: how you 'created a desktop entry', and how you installed Webstorm. Does Webstorm not appear in the applications menu anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that the desktop entry works, then the easiest way is to put it under `/usr/share/applications` (you will need sudo rights), then logout and login again and the ubuntu mate menu will auto-detect it. You can right click afterwards and choose "Add to panel".

You can also right click to panel and choose "Add to panel", then choose "Custom Application Launcher" and copy the "Exec" line of your desktop entry to the "Command" section.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like it would succeed. However, the statement, 'put it under' the usr/share/application folder is unhelpful. Which 'it' do we 'put it under' that folder,  Thanks...